# Match indexes of two arrays in PHP to pair data

Tags: php, arrays, forms, file, upload

I am doing a form with multiple files upload, for each file input there is a title input and I want to match the title with the file in order to be able to rename the file with the title.

I don't know how to match indexes of the two arrays to be able to do this.

Could someone help me? Thx

Here is my code so far ...

PHP :

```
$target_dir = 'files/';

if(isset($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['title'])){
    $total_titles = count($_POST['title']);
    for($key = 0; $key < $total_titles; $key++) {

        // Clean retrieved client data
        $pageName= $_POST['titles'];

    }

        // Check files 
        if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {

            // Count the number of uploaded files
            $total_files = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

            // Loop on uploaded files
            for($key = 0; $key < $total_files; $key++) {

                // Check if file is selected
                if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key]) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$key] > 0) {
        
                    $original_filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key]; 
                    
                    // Get the file extension
                    $extension = pathinfo($original_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
                    
                    // Get filename without extension
                    $filename_without_extension = basename($original_filename, '.'.$extension);

                    // Generate new filename
                    $new_filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename_without_extension) . '_' . '.' . $extension; 
                    // Upload the file with new name
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_dir . $new_filename);

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <!-- Page names -->
        <form class="form col-xl-6" action="" id="page_list_section" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" >
            <input type="file" name="userfile[]" > 
            <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" >
            <input type="file" name="userfile[]" > 
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" > 
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should really be careful with letting users upload files! The code you submitted allows for attackers to perform [Unrestricted File Upload](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload). They can for example upload a .php file to execute their code on your website and allow them to take over your entire site. The website linked above also shows how to prevent it. Here is another direct link: https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload#prevention-methods-solutions-to-be-more-secure

Comment: Be aware that you have duplicated `<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" >` string.

Comment: thx, it is on purpose, I need to test multiple files uploads

Comment: Thx, actually it is a raw code to test, I will introduce later verification to prevent vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the match:

```
for($key = 0; $key < $total_files; $key++) {
   $title = $_POST['title'][$key];
   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$key];
}
```